# Convert .Net ref (%) to native (&)

Tags: visual-c++, reference, c++-cli, interop, mixed-mode

How can I convert a C++/CLI `int %tmp` to native C++ `int &tmp`?

```
void test(int %tmp)
{
    // here I need int &tmp2 for another pure C++ function call
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void your_function(int *);
void your_function2(int &);

void test(int %tmp)
{
    int tmp2;
    your_function(&tmp2);
    your_function2(tmp2);
    tmp=tmp2;
}
```

Comment: this will almost certainly give an error: compiler cannot convert from int* to int&

Comment: @stijn: That depends on the signature of "your_func". See my changed example.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the existing answers properly handle in/out parameters, let alone any advanced use cases.

This should work for all cases where `other_func` does not keep the reference after it returns:

```
void test(int %tmp)
{
    pin_ptr<int> pinned_tmp = &tmp;
    other_func(*pinned_tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this, works fine:

```
  //in the C++ dll
void testFunc( int& n )
{
  n = 5;
}

  //in the CLI app
[DllImport( "my.dll", EntryPoint = "?exported_name_here",
   CallingConvention = CallingConvention::StdCall )]
void TestFunc( int& );

void test( int% tmp ) 
{
  int n;
  TestFunc( n );
  tmp = n;
}
```